# Why do webpages load so slowly the longer I use them?

Tags: javascript, django, web-frontend

I configured the webfront with Django and downloaded the modules using cdnjs.

The contents composed inside are about 20 3d graphs of 120*50 size made with vis.js and 2d graphs made with plotly.

I don't see this as the cause of the slowdown. Because when I first loaded the web page it took about 8 seconds and the next day it suddenly took about 1 minute to load.

I left it open until the next day without closing the webpage and doing nothing. When I try to test the web page the next day, it takes a long time to load. Clearing the cache and refreshing didn't work, but I had to turn the computer off and on to speed it up again.
I don't know why there is such a difference.
If anyone knows the cause, please let me know.

When I checked with Google Developer Tools, it took a long time to load in JavaScript. When I loaded the webpage the previous day, the script that took 5 seconds to load took more than 1 minute the next day.

I don't know where the web page takes to load, so I hope I get some hints. I want to know why the JavaScript loading is wrong with the time of the previous day and the next day.

Comment: This is unanswerable as is.  Lots of things could be happening.  The answers lie in the various tabs of dev tools and the code that is running.

Comment: Have you added bootstrap cdn files in multiple template. for ex: if you add bootstrap cdn file in base.html file and also in other templates then it loads slow. I faced this issue by adding bootstrap cdn file in base.html and other templates

Comment: @James 
thank you : ). I'll have to look into the devtools more or look into the code more.

Comment: @Manoj Tolagekar 
Thanks for the hint. I hadn't thought of that part.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.